# What causes noises in the house such as pops, creaks from walls, car windows, TV and wardrobes?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics

Here in the Middle East ,as you know,  the weather is hot outside and we have air conditioning inside our homes / offices and cars. Sometimes there are noises in the house like pops or creaks from walls, car windows, TVs, or wardrobe (anything, not necessarily things made of wood). What causes these noises?

Answer (score 3):

There could be numerous reasons for these sounds but I believe there one major factor contributing them. Notice that you mentioned you use a lot of air-conditioning while the outside is hot. This means there are often relatively high temperature differences and hence rapid expansion and contraction of materials inside the house, car etc. Suppose, you turn on the air-conditioner in the room with a timer and this causes the material in the wardrobe to contract. After the air-conditioner is turned off(and its hot outside again) the materials would again expand. Thus these frequent expansions and contractions are what likely cause the noises as the materials adjust to deformation.

Here are a few helpful links to understand more of the specifics:
https://lifehacker.com/strange-house-noises-explained-and-how-to-fix-them-1569420462

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-my-air-conditioner-making-a-cracking-popping-sound

Comment: the popping comes from the transition between static and sliding friction in the joints of the house.  as the parts of the house heat or cool nonuniformly, the expansion and contraction stresses build up under the influence of static friction until they are suddenly released under the influence of sliding friction.